# CSS3 Reset Animation Requires Timeout (if set animation from external style sheet)

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have a CSS animation. I apply it to a span within my div element with class span. I apply it from an external style sheet:

```
.skill > span { width:100%; -moz-animation:anim-skill 2s ease-out; -webkit-animation:anim-skill 2s ease-out; }

.anim-skill {width:100%; animation:anim-skill 2s ease-out; -moz-animation:anim-skill 2s ease-out; -webkit-animation:anim-skill 2s ease-out; -o-animation:anim-skill 2s ease-out;}

@keyframes anim-skill { from {width:0px;} to  {width:100%} }
```

When I want to reset the animation during run time I do this:

```
var mySkill = document.querySelector('.skill');
var bar = mySkill.childNodes[0];
//make it "from" state
bar.style.animation = 'none';
mySkill.style.width = 0;

//make it run
setTimeout(function () {
    mySkill.style.width = '';
    bar.style.animation = '';
}, 20);
```

This is very hacky. Is there a way to reset the animation this without using setTimeout? Note: If my timeout is 10ms or less it doesnt work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can not remove the class and set it again, without leaving the browser to render itself.

The non hacky way to do this is a little bit more sophisticated: make the animation remove itself

a quick and dirty implementation of this can be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("test");

    ele.addEventListener( 'webkitAnimationEnd', 
    function( event ) { ele.className = ""; }, false );
})
```

This will remove the animation class from the element, when the animation finishes. Afterwards, you can set the class again, without problems

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4f9e/)

Comment: Ah! Superb thanks man!! I'll use this method instead! :) Then later on when I want to start the animation i just set the animation again. :)